# Comme ça - meaning

Tags: sens

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Marseille:

- C'est quoi, cette montre ?
- C'est moi qui l'ai achetée. Pourquoi ?
- Comme ça.

The literal translation ("like that") makes no sense here. The English subtitle have translated "Comme ça" as "I just wondered", but I have no idea how the former could mean the latter. Is there a more accurate translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a correct translation. You say ***comme ça*** to explain there was no specific reason.

Often, ***pour rien*** is added to make clear there is no hidden agenda.

There is a different ***comme ça*** in the expression ***c'est comme ça*** that means: it is that way and not another.

Comment: Would perhaps "Just wondering" get the meaning across better as an informal idiomatic saying?

Comment: @CJDennis Indeed. "Just wondering" also means there is nothing particular to worry about.